# MySQL function pass a parameter from query

Tags: mysql, function, parameters, subquery

I have a function that will take a user's id as a parameter and do stuff using that parameter. I would like to call that function for several users.

For a single user I successfully use:

```
SELECT myFuncFoo(1);
```

And for multiple users I tried this without luck:

```
SELECT users.id as uid, 
(SELECT myFuncFoo(uid))
FROM users;
```

I also tried without aliases:

```
SELECT users.id,
(SELECT myFuncFoo(users.id))
FROM users;
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following if you want to execute `myFuncFoo()` for every row:

```
SELECT users.id,
myFuncFoo(users.id)
FROM users;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select myFuncFoo(uid) from(select uid from users where uid=1);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: select uid,myFunFoo(uid) from users